# 2 stacked buttons with dropdowns 100% width of container

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have searched over and over again for a solution to 2 problems that i have in a responsive page regarding 2 buttons that show dropdowns on click and i didn't manage to find something that works in my case.

Issue 1: show the dropdowns one at a time because right now, you can click on one and dropdown shows and if you click the second button, it's dropdown will open as well without closing the first dropdown.

Issue 2: make the dropdown as wide as the yellow container (like 100% of window with 10px padding). This must be done without changing the absolute position for .login-register

```js
          $('.login-toggle').click(function() {
            $('.login-menu').toggle();
            $('.login-toggle').toggleClass('activated');
          });

          $('.register-toggle').click(function() {
            $('.register-menu').toggle();
            $('.register-toggle').toggleClass('activated');
          });
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.login-register {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
.login {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.login .login-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px 26px 6px 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.login-menu,
.register-menu,
.user-forms .inner {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.user-forms {
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}
.register {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.register .register-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 26px;
}
.login-menu,
.register-menu {
  background-color: #0089d7;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  list-style: outside none none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="login-register">
    <div class="login">
      <a class="login-toggle" href="#/">Your account</a>
      <ul class="login-menu">
        <li>
          <div class="content user-forms">Login dropdown content</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="register">
      <a class="register-toggle" href="#/">Register</a>
      <ul class="register-menu">
        <li>
          <div class="content user-forms">Register dropdown content</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any solution must be ie8 compatible and responsive. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution #1 - No change to HTML

This code will resolve issue 1 and partially resolves issue 2. Due to the margin around the login/register buttons, it's not possible to have the unmodified HTML render out the menu with 100% width while having 10px margin. An alternative solution below resolves this but requires changes to the HTML.

```js
$('.login-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.login-menu').toggle();
  $('.login-toggle').toggleClass('activated');
  if ($('.login-toggle').hasClass('activated')) {
    $('.register-menu').hide();
    $('.register-toggle').removeClass('activated');
  }
});

$('.register-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.register-menu').toggle();
  $('.register-toggle').toggleClass('activated');
  if ($('.register-toggle').hasClass('activated')) {
    $('.login-menu').hide();
    $('.login-toggle').removeClass('activated');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0; // reset code snippet's margins to have consistent layout
}
.container {
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.login-register {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
.login {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.login .login-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px 26px 6px 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.login-menu,
.register-menu,
.user-forms .inner {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.user-forms {
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}
.register {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.register .register-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 26px;
}
.login-menu,
.register-menu {
  background-color: #0089d7;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  list-style: outside none none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.login-menu {
  margin-top: 28px; // prevent the menu from obstructing the register button
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="login-register">
    <div class="login">
      <a class="login-toggle" href="#/">Your account</a>
      <ul class="login-menu">
        <li>
          <div class="content user-forms">Login dropdown content</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="register">
      <a class="register-toggle" href="#/">Register</a>
      <ul class="register-menu">
        <li>
          <div class="content user-forms">Register dropdown content</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Solution #2 - requires changes to HTML

This code enhances the previous solution and will fully resolve issue 2, but requires an extra wrapping element around the menus to have the element span the entire width while maintaining 10px margin to the left and right.

```js
$('.login-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.login-menu-wrapper').toggle();
  $('.login-toggle').toggleClass('activated');
  if ($('.login-toggle').hasClass('activated')) {
    $('.register-menu-wrapper').hide();
    $('.register-toggle').removeClass('activated');
  }
});

$('.register-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.register-menu-wrapper').toggle();
  $('.register-toggle').toggleClass('activated');
  if ($('.register-toggle').hasClass('activated')) {
    $('.login-menu-wrapper').hide();
    $('.login-toggle').removeClass('activated');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0; // reset code snippet's margins to have consistent layout
}
.container {
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.login-register {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
.login {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.login .login-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px 26px 6px 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.login-menu-wrapper,
.register-menu-wrapper,
.user-forms .inner {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.user-forms {
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}
.register {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.register .register-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 26px;
}
.login-menu-wrapper,
.register-menu-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin: 0;
}
.login-menu,
.register-menu {
  background-color: #0089d7;
  color: #fff;
  list-style: outside none none;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.login-menu-wrapper {
  margin-top: 29px; // prevent the menu from obstructing the register button
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="login-register">
    <div class="login">
      <a class="login-toggle" href="#/">Your account</a>
      <div class="login-menu-wrapper">
        <ul class="login-menu">
          <li>
            <div class="content user-forms">Login dropdown content</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="register">
      <a class="register-toggle" href="#/">Register</a>
      <div class="register-menu-wrapper">
        <ul class="register-menu">
          <li>
            <div class="content user-forms">Register dropdown content</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan. Solution 2 was the best to solve both issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
    $('.login-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.login-menu').toggle();
    $('.login-toggle').toggleClass('activated');
    $('.register-menu').hide();
    });

$('.register-toggle').click(function() {
     $('.register-menu').toggle();
     $('.register-toggle').toggleClass('activated');
    $('.login-menu').hide();
});
```

When you click in the register login button you will activate the register display none class and the same to register button.